# Reading integers from file in separate arrays, one digit at a time, in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a text file that contains several lines, each line containing two very large integers.

I need to read the first integer on the line, store each one of its digits in an int array, read the second integer on the line, store each one of its digits in another int array. Then I should perform some operations (adding them, multiplying them etc), then repeat the procedure for the second line in the text file and so on.

I don't know how to read the integers this way. I would be able to read one integer only as an array of digits, but I don't know how to differentiate between the integers separated by space, much less how to tell the compiler when to switch the line.

The reason why I can't read the integers as int variables is, as I said, that they are too large for common numeric operations, so I must do them the same way I would by hand. I've written functions to replicate the process, but they need arrays of digits.

I tried to use `fscanf` or `getline` , but anything similar will read both integers on the line in one single array. Also, anything that reads until a space is encountered will read ALL of my numbers, not only the ones on the line I'm at.

The ideal would be two arrays, each containing the digits of one integer, that I keep reinitialising every time I switch the line.

Any suggestions on how to do this (or ideas that follow a different approach to do the same) would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not use `char array` to store the digits? It's enough to store a digit in a byte.

Comment: That would solve my difficulties storing them. However, I'd probably hit a rough spot with the calculations, given that the way I thought the functions out was similar to this [approach](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/106466/)

Comment: Whether you store them as integers or characters shouldn't make much difference in the calculations.  It is trivial to convert ascii digits to their integer value.  Unless you really want to reinvent the wheel you might consider using a bignum library instead.

Comment: So I store them in char arrays and convert one character to a digit just before I need that particular digit array[i] for the calculations, correct?

Comment: I'm actually going to attempt this program. Give me a while and I'll post an answer. A bignum library is always a good option, but I'm just gonna try using two vector<vector<string>>, stringstream to convert to int and then either adding each digit up individually and carrying surplus to next multiple of ten, or some variant on that

Comment: Why don't use some multiprecision arithmetics libraries available? They'll have much more efficient string input/output and maths operations

Answer (score 0):

Using boost library (algorithm for string split function, and lexical cast for conversion), you may take a look at this code snippets - (without validation)

```
typedef std::vector<int> intarray;
intarray da[2];
std::string s;
std::fstream f(filename,std::ios::in);
while(!f.eof() && !f.fail())
{
    std::getline(f, s );
    std::vector<std::string> v;
    boost::algorithm::split(v, s, boost::algorithm::is_any_of(" "));

    for(int j = 0; j<1; ++j)
    {
        std::string fs = v.at(j);
        for(int i = 0; i<fs.size(); ++i)
        {
            try
            {
                int d = boost::lexical_cast<int>(fs.at(i));
                da[j].push_back(d);
            }
            catch(bad_lexical_cast& e)
            {
                std::cout << "caught exception.\n";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```